# How to use if else condition in multiple controllers without rewrite again

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Same If else condition i'm using in multiple controllers. In this condition only i'm rendering the data. So my application is getting slow.

- ) How to use the same if condition code in multiple controllers
- ) Without writing again and again how to write once and use it in multiple controllers.

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
 if (reply.Category == 'first') {
  console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
 console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
 console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
 console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
 }
 });
```

I want to use this forEach function in multiple controllers. For Example,

1. **FirstController.js:**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
 if (reply.Category == 'first') {
  console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
 console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
 console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
 console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
 }
 });
```

2. **SecondController.js :**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
 if (reply.Category == 'first') {
  console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
 console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
 console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
 console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
 }
 });
```

3. **ThirdController.js :**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
 if (reply.Category == 'first') {
  console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
 console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
 console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
 console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
 }
 });
```

4. **FourthController.js :**

```js
$scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
 if (reply.Category == 'first') {
  console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
 console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
 console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
 } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
 console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
 }
 });
```

Like this i'm writing in my application.

**$scope.responseData = reply.data;**

This is my API Response. How can I do this?

I have one commonService,js file. But $scope will not accept in service file. So I could not able to achieve this. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can the move that code into separate  angular service and inject that service into your controller.

The pseudo code looks like below.

```js
function Service() {

   function processResponseData(scope) {

       scope.responseData.forEach(function(reply) {
         if (reply.Category == 'first') {
            console.log('rendering first object example app.getObject("data")');
         } else if (reply.Category == 'Second') {
            console.log('rendering second object example app.getObject("data")');
         } else if (reply.Category == 'third') {
            console.log('rendering third object example app.getObject("data")');
         } else if (reply.Category == 'fourth') {
            console.log('rendering fourth object example app.getObject("data")');
         }
      });
   }
}
```

and in the controller, you can just call like below.

```js
Service.processResponseData(scope);
```

if your forloop code uses any other variables , you can pass that to processResponseData and make use of them.

For more about services - look here - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Hope this helps.